# How to proxy http requests with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, proxy, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a bot with plain javascript that sends requests to a certain website without node.js or dependencies like jquery. I want to send every requests through a proxy, but I can't figure out how to do that with vanilla js.

I don't know where to even start. I've read the xhr documentation and found nothing about proxies. Google yielded nothing too.

Thanks!

Comment: If the proxy is properly configured you will make standard XHR call to the proxy as it is the final endpoint with no differencies

Comment: *"I'm writing a bot with plain javascript that sends requests to a certain website without node.js or dependencies like jquery."* Are you doing this from code in a web page, then? If not, what environment? If so: 1. Are you aware of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)? It's likely to prevent you doing what you want to do. 2. You can't use a different proxy than the one the browser is set up with (if any).

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini What I'm interested in is making the http requests from my client look like they came from another via a proxy.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I am aware of the same origin policy. I just disable CORS in my browser while running the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two broad categories of proxy server (that we need to care about for the purposes of this question).

- Ones designed to be set up as an HTTP proxy for a client. These require that the client be configured to use the proxy (for example, see [this university's guide to using their proxy](https://www2.aston.ac.uk/library/staff/mozillaproxy)). You **cannot** use client-side JavaScript to make a browser use this kind of proxy.
- Ones which present as a regular HTTP server but which determine what response to make by making an HTTP request to a different server (as opposed to reading a static file or executing a CGI program). To use these: Just make an HTTP request to a URL hosted by the proxy server.

Comment: Ok so I'm probably interested in the first kind. What I want is to make it seem like a different client sent the request. So that cannot be done from a browser? Can I use node.js for that then?

Comment: "So that cannot be done from a browser?" — Correct.

Comment: "Can I use node.js for that then?" — You could write an HTTP proxy server in node.js (although it would be easier to install an off-the-shelf one). You would still need to configure the browser to use it.

Comment: Well let's say I have the IP and port of a working proxy server. How would I send a request through that proxy in node?

Comment: Depends on the type of proxy. For instance, if it was a SOCKS5 proxy, use https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-https-client

Comment: And for a http proxy? Thank you for answering. I'm trying to upvote your answer, but it's not letting me

Comment: [You need 15 reptuation to upvote answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-agent